# How to enable browser search result highlighting in scroll bar for overflow: auto elements

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

My page layout features a header and a main element. I set the main element via css to `overflow: auto`, so that a scroll bar appears whenever the content is larger than the screen.

However when I press `Ctrl+F` to toggle the browser search and search for something, the results on the page are highlighted as usual but the "minimap" of search results in the scroll bar that usually is there is missing.

I can bring that "minimap" back when I remove the `overflow: auto` from the main element, however that makes the scroll bar go over all the page and not just the main element as I would prefer to.

I tried this in current versions of Chrome as well as Firefox and both show the same behavior.

This element is the only scrolling one and the scroll bar is on the very right of the window - it just starts below the header element, which I find aesthetically much more pleasing.

Is there any way that I can bring the search result highlighting "minimap" back to the scroll bar?

Comment: Is it the same problem with `overflow:scroll;`?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett: Yes, same problem with `overflow:scroll` both in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Not that I suggest you keep it on scroll, just curious as to whether it's just the adding of a rule that causes the scrollbar search highlight to disappear.

Comment: What if instead of specifying `overflow: auto` for the main section, you specify `overflow:hidden' for all elements other than main?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the default webkit scrollbar using css, javascript but it won't be easy to customize. Custom scrollbars come in handy in this case.

You can use the npm package **rc-slider** and customize the scrollbar based on your requirement. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oz4ue) is a working example of the scrollbar which highlights clickable markers at every 6th row.